# iOS push notifications - does application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: execute in main thread?

Tags: multithreading, ios, uikit, push-notification

I am wondering if an iOS app delegate's  `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` method executes in the main thread?

Ultimately I would like to know whether it is safe to put UI code in this method and if I should keep blocking code (like network interactions) out of it.

In general, are delegate methods executed in the main thread?

Answer (score 3):

The application delegate methods such as:

```
application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
```

are executed on the main thread.

If you want your application to be responsive for the user you should but blocking code in a background thread.

It is safe and recommended to execute UI code on the main thread.